# How to get two pieces from a link?

Tags: regex

The link looks like this

```
<a href="http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa538627.aspx" onclick="trackClick(this, '117', 'http\x3a\x2f\x2fmsdn.microsoft.com\x2fen-us\x2flibrary\x2fAa538627.aspx', '15');">ToolStripItemOwnerCollectionUIAdapter.GetInsertingIndex Method ...</a>
```

I want to retrieve the link (from href), and get the text in between get this.

Not sure how to do it

Comment: This would be better handled by something that does xml.

Comment: Furthermore, could you specify the programming language/framework you're using?

Comment: see my answer on a same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5914832/regex-match-pull-href-link-and-string-in-between-a-a/5917311#5917311

Answer (score 1):

```
/<a[^>]*\s+href\s*=\s*\"([^"]+)"[^>]*>(.*?)</a>/gi
```

This pattern should match most well-behaved links and provide the URL in group 1 and the text in group 2. For everything more complicated than that use a HTML parser.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work with C#, I'm doing

`string value = Regex.Replace(link, "/<a[^>]*\\s+href\\s*=\\s*\\\"([^\"]+)\"[^>]*>(.*?)</a>/gi", "");`